# Change color of an selected ListView item

Tags: android, listview, colors, background

i use a default android project and try to find a way to change the background color of a listview item that got selected. I know this is done via selectors. I tried to mimic the original look and behaviour coming from the holo themes and just change the color in there, but i failed. Can somebody explain to me how to get the original look and feel for listview items (longclick fade etc) and just change the color from this strange blue to something else?

What do I have to copy to my project from android sdk and where to change the selected color?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, i already know how to change the background of the items in my custom adapter. But my App is based on a default android project (two pane) and this project uses states for the list items on the left pane. I am very happy on how the states change, also the effects etc, just the selected color is what i dont like. Overriding by my own code seems not the right way here. So i tried changing the selectors created for this default project, yet i failed. I thought i get a copy from the sdk and just change the color without loosing any styles etc. But from where?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a custom `ArrayAdapter`, you'll have to define your `onClick()` listener on the second parameter of your `getView()` method. Usually it's called `convertView`, but it doesn't have to.

This second parameter, speaking very vaguely, references to the layout of each row. So when you want to change the background of your row, simply add a `onClickListener()` on the second parameter, and change the background:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    convertView.setBackground(your_new_background);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, i know. In this one case its not what i want to do. Isnt the selector underlying setting the color and then i change it again? Sounds the wrong way for me.

Answer (score 0):

dude you can use custom adapter for your listview. 
In custom xml files u can change everthing.
For detail example follow [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Hi, i know this all. In this one case its not what i want to do. See my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you asking , but watever I understood I think you want something like

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

 @override 
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

       ..............................
            view.setBackground("Your color");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, i know. In this one case its not what i want to do. See my comment above